# Catalina equivalent to systemctl status?

Tags: command-line, launchd

I'm trying to wrap my head around launchctl.

I need to run the MacOS equivalent of `systemctl status zabbix-agent`

I am trying with `launchctl print com.zabbix.zabbix_agentd` but I get:

```
Unrecognized target specifier. <service-target> takes a form of <domain-target>/<service-id>.
Please refer to `man launchctl` for explanation of the <domain-target> specifiers.
Usage: launchctl print <domain-target> | <service-target>
```

I'm a bit at loss here, if anyone can help me, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: I think you need to call `launchctl print GUI/(id -u) /Library/LaunchAgents/com.zabbix.zabbix_agentd`, where `id -u` will return UID. You can replace `id -u` with a specific, desired UID. https://ss64.com/osx/launchctl.html

Comment: Hello @Zingam! Thanks for your input. I'm getting the same error: `$ launchctl print GUI 501 /Library/LaunchAgents/com.zabbix.zabbix_agentd                                   1
Unrecognized target specifier. <service-target> takes a form of <domain-target>/<service-id>.
Please refer to man launchctl for explanation of the <domain-target> specifiers.
Usage: launchctl print <domain-target> | <service-target>`

Comment: Please check my comment below for more ideas. Unfortunately it's a legacy syntax. That's all I can say at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

`launchctl list` will list display a list of current jobs, including the job's current PID (if it is running) and most-recent exit status (if it previously exited). Prepending `sudo` will also display system launchdaemons.

The unix command `grep` can be used to filter the output of stdin. So, to get the status of a job with the label `com.zabbix.zabbix_agentd`, you can do:

```
launchctl list | grep com.zabbix.zabbix_agentd
```

Prefix with `sudo` if zabbix-agent is installed as a system daemon.

Comment: Thanks for your input @Wowfunhappy! However, does launchctl list show the same output as systemctl info?

Comment: XNU is not Linux and there is no command that's exactly the same. I thought you were trying to figure out whether the job was running. If that's not it, what information are you actually hoping to find?

Comment: Thanks again for your help @Wowfunhappy! I am hoping to get the Control Group for the process and more precise job status info such as: `Active: active (running) since Tue 2022-05-31 01:42:44 UTC; 2 days ago`.    Also, when there is some sort of problem, this `status` option shoots back a lot of useful info.

Comment: `launchctl list` is a legacy subcommand. Is there any alternative way to get the status reliably? Particulary from root I want to get the status/list of statuses for each logged in user. `sudo -u user launchctl list` returns a list of system daemons just like `launchctl list` from a root context.

Comment: @Zingam Where did you read that `launchctl list` was legacy? I'm a bit surprised `sudo -u` didn't work for your use-case. I'm not that knowledgable about UNIX permissions, but my guess would be there's some `sudo` incantation necessary to get the output you're looking for. You might ask a new question.

Comment: @Wowfunhappy `man launchctl`. I can't state the source but the solution is to `launchctl asuser UID sudo -u UseName launchctl list`, which unfortunately is also a legacy subcommand. In Syntax 2.0 it doesn't seem to be a good way of obtaining service status but I went with the above solution for now.